# Why is Internet Explorer prepending filedownload.php/path= to any link to a file

Tags: php, sql-server, internet-explorer, iis-7, cross-browser

Had a server go down recently and just reinstalled IIS and replaced inetpub with the backed up files.  What's odd is on internet explorer certain div fields have a green background now and all direct links to files are prepending filedownload.php/path=.  The website acts completely normal in Chrome and Firefox.  For example a link that starts as:

> https://$company.com/$foldername/$file.xlsx

Turns into:

> http://$company.com/file_download.php?path=http%3A%2F%2F$company.com%2F$foldername%2F$file.xlsx

And obviously doesn't work anymore.  What's odd is in the code it's just pulling the link from a MSSQL database row/column, no interpretation or funny stuff.

Comment: Did you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: Yes, it didn't change anything.

Comment: It can be possible that your back up files are little different than your old files which was working correctly. You can try to check the CSS files and check whether there are any rewrite rules get execute or some configuration files have different settings.

Comment: Unfortunately I've looked and I'm not seeing any difference between the backups and current.  I've never seen anything like this, it appears to be functioning the same for at least 100 of our users.